# Append 30 on end of the scroll using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have value `30` in one variable. I want to append it on div on scroll.
starting value should be 0 and when we scroll it should be append with appropriate value and when we scroll end of the document the value should be 30.  [Fiddle attached](http://jsfiddle.net/qWX59/).

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var val = 30;
    var dd = $(document).scrollTop();
    var mm = dd/val
    $('div').text(Math.round(mm))
})
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it clear what you're trying to do. At the moment it makes very little sense.

Comment: Your code seems to change `val` depending on the scroll height... so what's the problem with it?

Comment: check my fiddle, when you scroll down the value are going up to 20 it should be 30

Comment: Furthermore it depends on the window height with your current version. At the moment, you check the upper side of the scrollbar, so it will never reach the 100% of value 30.

Comment: there is any way to make it happen.

Comment: You need to check the bottom end of the viewable area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var val = 30;
    var dd = $(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
    var mm = dd * val
    $('div').text(Math.round(mm))
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qWX59/1/

Answer (score 2):

Set `val` based on body and window heights. This gives you the amount of travel for scroll

```
var val = ($(window).height() - $('body').height()) / 30;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var dd = -$(document).scrollTop();
    var mm = dd / val
    $('div').text(Math.round(mm))

})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qWX59/2/